# PHP - Adding subtitle to video in server side

Tags: php, video, subtitle

I wonder is there any method to merge subtitle to a video? both of them stored on the server...

I'm trying to create an apps that will have custom subtitle and then upload the subtitle to the server and merge it up with the video. Final step is to upload the video to the user's YouTube account.

Is there any way I could do this?
With PHP alone maybe not, but extension/plugin maybe?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Ahmad, welcome to SO! This site lives with the fact, that also the askers put some effort into their questions. You will more likely get an answer if you do some researches and explain, what you already found out. Otherwise your question might be closed unanswered.

Comment: http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20burn%20subtitles%20into%20the%20video You will need ffmpeg, but if you are on shared hosting, i am not sure that provider will install it/allow you to use it...

Comment: @nevermind so ffmpeg is not like just putting it on the directory of the host then run the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Could Use http://www.ffmpeg.org

> FFmpeg is a complete, cross-platform solution to record, convert and stream audio and video. It includes libavcodec - the leading audio/video codec library